# call to specific thread in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

In my multi thread project i have several threads running simultaneously, the only waiting function i could find is pthread_join but it does not invoke a specific thread, but instead it blocks the current running thread until the thread that I passed as parameter to pthread_join was over. i am looking for a way to invoke a specific one.

```
typedef struct proc{
    int sys_number; //unique node ID i give the thread
    pthread_t process; 
} thread;

thread proccesses[N];

thread = pthread_create(&(proccesses[i].process), NULL, printme, &(proccesses[i].sys_number));
```

then when i want to call lets say proccesses[i].process i use:

```
pthread_join(proccesses[0].process, &status);
```

but instead it runs all the processes that were opened and waiting, i am looking for the equivalent of waitpid in processes.

EDIT: I am looking for a way to choose which thread will run next

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It's confusing.  Waiting for a thread will stop the current thread.  Are you asking to be signalled when all or a specific thread has ended without stopping the main thread?

Comment: hello, yes when i use pthread_join the current thread will stop until the thread passed as parameter to the function is over. i am looking for a way to choose which thread will run next

Comment: There are not build-in functions to pause/continue threads. If you want threads to be synchronised in any way you need to implement this your own, probably using one or more  conditions and/or mutexes.

Comment: There is no mechanism to choose which specific thread will run code.  That requires solving the [producer-consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) problem.  Very common, any GUI app uses it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can implement a simple `pause()` / `resume()` controller for each thread via mutex and condition variables.